# Swift iOS Xcode 6 - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm running into an error in Xcode 6 in Swift. I'm trying to create slide-navigation as demonstrated in this tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU

Screenshot -
http://gyazo.com/283f9111ede347272ce69d9a5bea81ba

I understand that the value is returned as nil which means that something isn't being calculated or accounted for in the app but I don't know where to begin looking for that.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Jamie Mathieson

Comment: Firstly, I tried to make the initial scrollview the initial viewcontroller and this allowed me to correctly use the scrollviews by swiping. Although, this is not as intended. Before the scrollviews load, there are login/sign up scrollviews and these must happen first. So, I decided to put the scrollviews in a function and call this after I had loaded all other scroll views. This is where I got this error -> http://i.gyazo.com/1c6b72d5c7b48f3b7b4932154db43ab4.png Uncaught exception of type NSException Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a variable like

```
var name?
```

and before assigning it a value you go, `name!` it will crash cause you are converting an optional value to a non-optional, but the optional is nil which isnt allowed.

you could also have a variable like

```
var name!
```

and are trying to use it before assigning a value to it